# Access 'Response Time (ms)' windows disk counter from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

In perfmon there is a 'Response Time (ms)' column on disk tab.
It shows response time by process.

How can I get this value in powershell?
I didn't find any solution in the internet.

WMI serves just basic stats, no response/latency time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

which version of windows / windows server are you referring?

In general you can use the typeperf.exe util to query performance counters.

Executing `typeperf.exe -q` will list all loaded counters.

If you insist on using powershell, you should use Get-WmiObject to get the data from the correct performance class.
if your'e not sure what is the class, running `Get-CimClass *perf*` will list all available classes.

the classes are divided to two main types: formatted and raw (formatted are the ones that show you the data as seen in perfmon).

Comment: "If you insist on using powershell"...(!) You should use Powershell for everything you possibly can these days ;-)

Comment: I don't agree, powershell is amazing but sometimes a few lines in Batch are a lot faster.